# Java createNativeQuery Insert datetime

Tags: java, sql, datetime

Estou tentando fazer um Insert em um banco cujas datas são `datetime2(7)`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

Query u = em.createNativeQuery(insert);
u.setParameter(1, sdf );
```

Está dando o seguinte erro:

> Implicit conversion from data type varbinary to date is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: ja tentou usar sdf.format(date)

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDateFormat` não é uma data. Esta classe é usada para formatar datas (transformar `Date` para `String`) e fazer *parsing* (transformar `String` em `Date`) - veja a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Se o campo no banco de dados é uma data, passe o `Date` - `java.util.Date`, ou `java.sql.Date` (ou `java.sql.Timestamp`, ou o que você estiver usando) para `setParameter`.

---

Se você tem uma `String` e quer salvar a data, neste caso você usa o `SimpleDateFormat` para converter a `String` para `Date`:

```
Date date = sdf.parse(stringQueContemAData);
```

E em seguida, passe o `Date` para o método `setParameter`:

```
u.setParameter(1, date);
```

Mas como você não especificou qual a entrada e saída (se é `String`, `Date`, etc), não dá pra ajudar mais que isso.

---

As datas não têm formato, somente valores (veja [este artigo](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) que explica bem esta sutil diferença). Só porque você está vendo a data em um formato específico, não quer dizer necessariamente que ela está naquele formato.

Internamente, cada linguagem, API ou banco de dados grava os tipos de data em um formato interno, mas que não importa para quem as usa. Quando a data é exibida (impressa, gravada num arquivo, mostrada na tela, etc), aí é escolhido um formato para exibição. Mas isso não quer dizer que a data está gravada naquele formato.

Dito isso, se o campo no banco é do tipo datetime, apenas passe o `Date` para `setParameter`.

Comment: como faço para jogar no banco a data no formato datetime2(7)?

Comment: Datas não têm formato.  Só porque elas são mostradas em um formato, não quer dizer que elas estão necessariamente salvas neste formato. Salve o objeto Date e pronto.

Comment: @user113924 Se você tem mais dúvidas, ou se vai acrescentar mais informação, [edite a sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/300705/edit) (não acrescente dúvidas nas respostas). E para salvar uma data, você passa o objeto `Date` para `setParameter` (conforme eu indiquei acima na minha resposta)

Comment: @user113924 Novamente: não edite a minha resposta para acrescentar informações referentes à sua pergunta. Edita [a sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/300705/edit) para isso: coloque as suas tentativas, entradas e saídas (o que você obteve e o que gostaria de ter obtido), etc. Leia na central de ajuda como fazer um [mcve]